# Break out of std::visit once the desired alternative is found

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I often find myself using the following pattern to get the desired variant type from a container of variants:

```
for(auto&& Variant : variantContainer)
{
    // If the variant types match, do something
    std::visit([this, &Variant](auto&& arg)
    {
        using argType = typename std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;                                       // e.g. `Field<int>`
        if (std::holds_alternative<argType>(Variant))                                           // if the current variant has the same type as the field
        {
            // do something, then preferably stop checking
            // the other possible variants
        }
    }, Variant);        
}
```

However, per [cppreference.com's](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) statement on `std::visit` complexity:

> If the number of variants is larger than 1, the invocation of the callable object has no complexity requirements.

It's probably typically linear complexity, so I'm wondering if there is any mechanism to break out of `std::visit` early once I've gotten what I need from it?

Comment: I don't think so. I also can't imagine a reason why complexity should not be linear.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You're using `std::visit` on `Variant`. Your lambda will therefore be called with the value and type stored by `Variant`. Therefore, `holds_alternative<argType>` will *always be true*. That's what `visit` is for. Also, the number of variants you're passing is 1, so it's not clear how that sentence applies to you.

Comment: @NicolBolas it's `holds_alternative<argType>` on the Variant, not the arg... At least in my VS 2017 debugger, the call to visit is happening once _for each type in the variant union_

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus: "*it's holds_alternative<argType> on the Variant, not the arg...*" But the source of `argType` is `Variant`. The whole point of `visit` is to extract the current alternative in the variant and call your functor with that value. Which will therefore be of the same type as the current alternative in the variant. There is no circumstance where that condition won't evaluate to `true`. Worst-case, it will be a compile error, if the variant type contains multiple instances of the given type.

Comment: @NicolBolas you're right. I had a bad understanding of `std::visit` and the code works as expected without the check. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of a way you would be able to inform `std::visit` that you wish to "break out", without `std::visit` explicitly inspecting something like a return value. As an example, imagine a custom version of `visit` that expects a "special" return type:

```
struct visitor
{
    auto operator()(int, int)     { return continue_{}; }
    auto operator()(int, float)   { return break_{}; }
    auto operator()(float, int)   { return continue_{}; }
    auto operator()(float, float) { return continue_{}; }
};
```

Its implementation would be able to detect whether the invoked `visitor::operator()` overload returned a `continue_` or a `break_` and stop.

---

Regardless, I think you shouldn't worry much:

- `libc++` implements multi-variant visitation by [creating a `constexpr` matrix of function pointers and then invoking the matching one](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/variant#L420-L430).
- `libstdc++` seems to do something similar by [generating a multidimensional "vtable"](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/variant#L1371-L1388).

Comment: Maybe make the return type `variant<continue_, break_>`?

Comment: void return type?

Comment: @BrianRodriguez: I think that "breaking out" could be done at compile-time by checking the return type with something like `std::is_same_v`. I need to give this more thought but my intuition is that a `variant` here is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to capture a break flag by reference.

```
// surely you don't want a copy?
for(auto&& Variant : variantContainer)
{
    auto should_break = false;

    // If the variant types match, set the value
    std::visit([this, &should_break](auto&& arg)
    {
        // arg is one of the Ts... in the variant

        this->doTheRightThing(arg);
        if (shouldCauseBreak(arg))
            should_break = true;
    }, Variant);        

    if (should_break)
        break;
}
```

Comment: good call with the `rvalue`reference. What I was actually looking to do was stop checking the other possible variants, not the other contained elements. I edited the question code to try and make it more clear.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus the whole purpose of std::visit is that it only executes the lambda on one of the variant types - the current one.